# Kubernetes keep getting ErrImagePull

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to install Tremolo's OpenUnison Orchestra login portal - 
https://github.com/OpenUnison/openunison-k8s-login-activedirectory. However, when I'm running the installation command -

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TremoloSecurity/kubernetes-artifact-deployment/master/src/main/bash/deploy_openunison.sh | bash -s /path/to/orchestra-configmaps /path/to/orchestra-secrets https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenUnison/openunison-k8s-login-activedirectory/master/src/main/yaml/artifact-deployment.yaml`

K8S tries to deploy `docker.io/tremolosecurity/kubernetes-artifact-deployment:1.1.0`

But I keep getting the following error(Using `kubectl descrive pods -n openunison-deploy`):

`Failed to pull image "docker.io.tremolosecurity.kubernetes-artifact-deployment:1.1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context canceled`

And then there is an event of `Error: ErrImagePull` and then `Back-off pulling image..` and it goes back on.

How can I fixed it?

**EDIT**

I tried to simply `docker pull docker.io/tremolosecurity/kubernetes-artifact-deployment:1.1.0` and it seems that there is a `100MB` which takes a lot of time to download (more than 15 minutes already and not half way done) could this be the problem? As the error states that it failed pulling the image from docker.io...

Comment: Does the image size is too big. Anyidea. If so then try to increase `--image-pull-progress-deadline` on the kubelet as mentioned here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59376#issuecomment-377606902

Comment: Also try to pull that image manually using `docker pull` command.

Comment: Could you try copying the contents of that last file in your install command `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenUnison/openunison-k8s-login-activedirectory/master/src/main/yaml/artifact-deployment.yaml` locally, modifying in the last section by removing `docker.io/` from the `image: docker.io/tremolosecurity/kubernetes-artifact-deployment:1.1.0` line, and run `kubectl apply -f /path/to/your/modified/file`?

Comment: @mchawre How can I chage that flag for kubelet? I could not find how to update flag values.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above by community [mchawre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6790948/mchawre) and  [Amit Kumar Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061413/amit-kumar-gupta):

**1**. For `--image-pull-progress-deadline` please verify your service by `systemctl status kubelet`, add option in the section `ExecStart=--image-pull-progress-deadline=10m` into your kubelet.service and run:

```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
   sudo systemctl restart restart kubelet
```

verify kubelet flags by running:

`journalctl -u kubelet | grep flag`

**2**. In case you can pull image using docker please setup in your deployment spec:
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

**3**. Update your docker installation the latest one and [Cleanup docker resources](https://gist.github.com/bastman/5b57ddb3c11942094f8d0a97d461b430)

```
docker images
docker rmi <unused imgaes>
docker system prune
docker image prune -a
docker info
```

**4**. Due to other problem with your configuration please consider docker re-installation.

Hope this help.